# How to reverse a number in java in a user generated program

Tags: java

My teacher wants me to be able to ask this question an infinite number of times until the user decides to terminate it themselves. This works for the most part however, If I input a number too big I get an error because its a int data type. I have tried `long`s and `double`s to but for some reason I get answers like infinity or the negative of the numbers. How do I fix this so I can put in as long of a number that I want and still get the positive integer reversal? Thank You so Much. Please keep it simple. This is literally my 5th computer class in my life.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class reverseInt3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int reverse = 0;
        int number2;
        int reverse2 = 0;
        char repeat;

        System.out.println("Please enter any numbers you choose and I will reverse them for you");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        while( number != 0 )
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + number%10;
            number = number/10;
        }   

        System.out.println("Reverse of entered number is "+reverse);

        System.out.println("Do you want to repeat the process using different numbers? Y or N");
        repeat = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

        while( repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y')
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your new set of numbers");
            number2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();

            while( number2 != 0 )
            {
                reverse2 = reverse2 * 10;
                reverse2 = reverse2 + number2%10;
                number2 = number2/10;
            }       
        System.out.println("The reverse of entered number is "+reverse2);

        System.out.println("Do you want to repeat the process using different numbers? Y or N");
        repeat = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to just use `String` as your variable type?  That would allow it to be as long as you like.

Comment: After you reverse a number, but before you reverse the next, what is the value of `reverse2`?  What do you think it should be?

Comment: Go with [Java's BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead.

Comment: do reverse and reverse2 have to have different values?

Comment: Also if I use a [string] as my variable type wont it give me errors when i try to do arithmetic functions?

Comment: Try the following:  enter 0, y, 123, y, 789 ... and look at the results.  You’ll see the reversed values are: 0, 321, and 321987.  Any guesses as to how that 3rd value arises?

Comment: Because since its a value that's not 0 and I don't loop it correctly... How do I fix that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After you reversed 123, `reverse2` holds 321.   Then you are starting to reverse 789, so you multiply reverse2 by 10 (3210), add in the 9 (3219), and repeat for the next two digits.  Clearly, you need to clear out your old value first.  Any idea how to clear it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's talk about your problem:

*If the user input goes beyond the bound of int, long or double your program provides a negative reverse.*

That's because when you try to store a very big number in smaller capacity variable, an overflow happens and after that your stored number is not valid and if you try to print it you will get a negative number instead which is not the exact negative for the user input.

If you want to overcome this, one way is to store the user input in a String variable. Then you can check if the input (which is stored in a String type variable) is really an integer or not, and if it was, you can reverse it.

I don't think this is actually what your teacher want you to do. Because the algorithm of reversing an integer (you implemented) can not be used to reverse such a big integer stored in a String variable. So I think your code is good and get it easy because probably your teacher don't expect you to maintain very big integers now. If you so worry about some bigger integers you can use long instead of int but as you know it has its own limitation about 18 digits approximately and it should not be bigger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Your code is good for the start and I'm going to express some advice in order to provide a better and cleaner code:

It's obvious that you've repeated these part of codes:

```
System.out.println("Please enter any numbers you choose and I will reverse them for you");
number = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

and

```
while( number != 0 )
{
    reverse = reverse * 10;
    reverse = reverse + number%10;
    number = number/10;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println("Reverse of entered number is "+reverse);
```

If you studied *methods* so far, you may want to define these two first blocks in two different methods. One is responsible for getting input from user and the other one is responsible for getting an `int` as input and return the reversed `int` (If you used `long` for user input, this method's input and output should be of type `long`).

Another tip is why repeat those blocks? Why have two `number` and `number2` variables and also `reverse` and `reverse2`?

Isn't it better to omit them and write your `while` for the repetition of the process in the first time too? Start by initializing the `char repeat = 'Y';` and omit the first time you manually get the job done outside of the `while( repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y')` loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the reason the value overflows, goes negative, etc is because the results of one reversal are left as garbage in the `reverse2` accumulator during the reversal of the next number.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Thanks for the tip! I've missed that.

Comment: thank you. It helped a lot. One more question - how do incorporate 0's for instance if i put 025 to reverse it it comes back 52 instead of 520. Why is that?

Comment: @AJNeufeld how do I fix that problem

Comment: @dgl I think it's natural because in the beginning of the program you tell the user to enter integers and we know 025 is not a valid integer because it is equivalent to 25. But as I expressed in the answer if you want to support these exceptional situations you should store the user input in `String` variables and check them to be integers and then reverse the String by it's own capabilities. Moreover, in StackOverFlow when an answer is helping, you may select it as the answer by selecting the green check mark on the left side of the answer.

Comment: @mdgl As I mentioned in my other comment, "**Clearly**, you need to **clear** out your old value first. Any idea how to **clear** it?" I can't be any **clearer** without spelling out the answer; I'd hoped you'd have an "ah ha!" moment & come up with the solution yourself. What value should your accumulator have, so that if you multiplied it by 10 and added in a digit, the result only be that digit? Or what value did the accumulator start with where it worked? Such as your initial initialization value? Perhaps you need to repeat that assignment when you are about to reverse the next value.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Just had that moment. I wasnt thinking.

Comment: @mdgl Yippee.  Those moments are good, as long as you don't hit yourself too hard when they happen.  To be (_ahem_) clear, add the line `reverse2 = 0;` just before `while( number2 != 0 )`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I had just done that when I saw your comment. Thank you